# How to create zip with lzma compression

Tags: java, lzma

I know how to create zip archive:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
public class ZipCreateExample{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception  
        // input file 
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("F:/sometxt.txt");

        // out put file 
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("F:/tmp.zip"));

        // name the file inside the zip  file 
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("zippedjava.txt")); 

        // buffer size
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int count;

        while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
            System.out.println();
            out.write(b, 0, count);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to use lzma compression.

I found this project: https://github.com/jponge/lzma-java which creating compressed file but I don't know how I should combine it with my existing solution.

Comment: Neither Java's Zip util nor Commons-Compress support LZMA compression for each ZipEntry. It would probably take a day or two to extended Commons-Compress to support it by using the LZMA code above and overriding the checks for STORAGE | DEFLATE. In fact, it'd be nice if Commons-Compress could use a more extensible approach where the ZipArchiveEntries were extended with the required compression method, such as ZipArchiveEntryLZMA. As it is, there's too many checks in ZipArchiveOutputStream to do this quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Apache Commons Compress (1.6 released on 23-Oct-2013) supports LZMA compression.

Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html, specially the one regarding .7z compressing/uncompressing.

Say for example you want to store an html page from an HTTP Response and you want to compress it:

```
SevenZOutputFile sevenZOutput = new SevenZOutputFile(new File("outFile.7z"));

File entryFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + "web.html");
SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZOutput.createArchiveEntry(entryFile, "web.html");

sevenZOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);
sevenZOutput.write(rawHtml.getBytes());
sevenZOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
sevenZOutput.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the website you mentioned:

Adapted to your needs:

```
final File sourceFile = new File("F:/sometxt.txt");
final File compressed = File.createTempFile("lzma-java", "compressed");

final LzmaOutputStream compressedOut = new LzmaOutputStream.Builder(
        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(compressed)))
        .useMaximalDictionarySize()
        .useEndMarkerMode(true)
        .useBT4MatchFinder()
        .build();

final InputStream sourceIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));

IOUtils.copy(sourceIn, compressedOut);
sourceIn.close();
compressedOut.close();
```

(I don't know if it works, it is just the usage of the library and your code snippet)

Comment: as I said in my question this just create compressed file not compressed archive

Comment: Isn't it the same?...The output is just a compressed stream of bytes of the input(s), which is then written to a file.

Comment: nope it isnt because archive may contains a lot of compressed file

Answer (score 0):

[zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm) supports LZMA compression for zip archive.

```
ZipEntrySettings entrySettings = ZipEntrySettings.builder()
                                                 .compression(Compression.LZMA, CompressionLevel.NORMAL)
                                                 .lzmaEosMarker(true).build();
ZipSettings settings = ZipSettings.builder().entrySettingsProvider(fileName -> entrySettings).build();

Path file = Paths.get("F:/sometxt.txt");
Path zip = Paths.get("F:/tmp.zip");

ZipIt.zip(zip).settings(settings).add(file);
```